# dde client connection in Python?

Tags: python, dde

I want a simple dde (Dynamic Data Exchange) client print on console 
like this:

```
SYM  TIME ASK   BID   LAST    VOLUME
AMD  9:00 11.04 11.05 11.05   20000
CSCO 9:00 44.75 44.76 44.75   3000
```

I have found [some old code](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577654-dde-client/) and [some new code](https://gist.github.com/atsuoishimoto/ff8075c6eb1e73a03254). How I can adapt it for Python 3.6?

I encountered some problems with the print statement like on first code:

```
print "%s: %s" % (item, value)
```

Is that correct for Python 3.6?

ps: My excel formula is like =FDF|Q!'AMD.O;ask

Comment: [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is a build in function in Python 3.

Comment: Try `print(item, value)`.

Comment: Thanks ! but all 2 code(old new) need python 2.7, your information is useful anyway